# Intersection of two SearchQuerySets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, searchqueryset

So I have a similar model:

```
class Whatever(SlugMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth_models.User, related_name='user+', verbose_name=_('User'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=200)
```

I am trying to find all objects that belong to that user and that have a name which matches the searched term.

I have already understood that doing:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(text=searched_term).filter(user=user)
```

won't work. It returns to me the union of those two. However, I want the intersection of those two conditions, and not the union. I understand that this happens because the user and text belong to different models.

Answer (score 4):

Just to make sure we are on the same page what unions and intersections mean, let's take a short example:

Group A = `[1, 2, 3]`

Group B = `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Intersection of A and B would be `[2, 3]`

and union of A and B would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

If you are looking for intersection:

```
desired_queryset = Whatever.objects.filter(user=user, name=searched_term)
```

If you are looking for union:

```
from django.db.models import Q
desired_queryset = Whatever.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(name=searched_term))
```

Comment: Yes, I actually used the same operation, only I've used "text=searched_term" instead of "name=searched_term". It seems that there's another bug that causes strange results. If the searched_term's length is 1, this filter is just ignored. Will have to dig this deeper.